# Orthogonality and Linear Independence | Intuition

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I just like to conceptually understand linear independence and orthogonality. So in reality do one tests for whether say two vectors are co-linear and the other tests whether two vectors are perpendicular?

Comment: What does 'in reality' mean?

Comment: Linear independence is a property of a vector space. Given any vector space $V$ and 2 vectors $v,w \in V$, you can test whether this are linearly dependent or not. However, to speak of orthogonality, we need more structure. Namely, an inner product. While orthogonal implies linearly independent, the converse is not true. Take, for example $(1,1)$ and $(1,0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard inner product.

Comment: @UnexpectedExpectation +1 for good summary but I quite didnt get when you say to speak of orthogonality "we need more structure" . Are you saying inner product is "structure" while cheking for linearly dependent is not structure?

Comment: For an abstract vector space $V$, it makes no sense to speak of orthogonality. We need some inner product $g$ on $V$. We then say that $v$ and $w$ are orthogonal to one another if $g(v,w)=0$.

Comment: Oh I see it makes so much sense. Is this the reason we have a special space defined i.e. inner product space because abstract vector space $V$ isnt sufficient to define orthogonality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll provide a less-than-formal description in the hopes it gives you the intuition you asked for.

Let’s start with orthogonality, which is the simpler of the two concepts in my opinion.

### Orthogonality

You’re correct that, if you’re thinking geometrically, orthogonal vectors are perpendicular. More generally, in an inner product space, two vectors are orthogonal if their inner product is zero.
This concept easily extends to a set of three or more vectors: a set of vectors is mutually orthogonal if all pairs of vectors in the set are orthogonal.

### Linear independence

It may be helpful to think of linear independence in terms of whether any vectors are 'unnecessary' or 'redundant', rather than in terms of collinearity.

Linear independence is a property of a set of vectors. If there are *only two vectors* then linear independence greatly simplifies. A set of two vectors is linearly independent if one vector is not a scaled version of the other. In other words, a set of two vectors $u$ and $v$ is linearly dependent if:

$u = c v$

for some non-zero scalar $c$.

Things gets more complicated when you move to *three or more vectors*. A set of three or more vectors is linearly dependent if at least one of the vectors (lets call it the unnecessary vector) is a linear combination of some (or all) of the remaining vectors. In other words, if the set of vectors is linearly dependent then you could create the unnecessary vector $u$ by scaling and adding some number of the remaining vectors (lets say three vectors $x$, $y$, and $z$):

$u = c_1 x + c_2 y + c_3 z$

for some non-zero scalars $c_1$, $c_2$, and $c_3$.

### Linear Dependence Example

Note that in the above example linear independence requires more than just "$u$ is not a scaled version of $x$, $y$, and $z$". Even if $u$ is not in the same "direction" as $x$, $y$, or $z$, the vector $u$ can still be a linear combination of $x$, $y$, and $z$.

To make this more concrete, let's assume that $x$, $y$, and $z$ are each unit vectors and they lie along the $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ axes in the three dimensional Cartesian coordinate system. Therefore, any point in this 3D space can be represented by a vector from the origin to that point, and this vector is some linear combination of unit vectors $x$, $y$, and $z$.

Next assume that:

$u = c_1 x + c_2 y + c_3 z$

for some non-zero scalar $c$.

This means vector $u$ 'points to' some point in the 3D space. We don't need $u$ to get to this point since we can instead use $c_1 x + c_2 y + c_3 z$. This shows that $u$ is "redundant".

### A final note

Since you asked about both orthogonality and linear independence, for the sake of completeness I'll just mention that a set of linearly dependent vectors can nevertheless contain some vectors which are orthogonal to each other. In the example above, vectors $x$, $y$, and $z$ are mutually orthogonal. If the set contained just these three vectors then the set would be linearly independent. However, when we add $u$ the set of four vectors becomes linearly dependent.

Comment: This makes sense. Your last comment though is little hard to grasp. How can a set of linearly dependent vectors be mutually orthogonal?

Comment: A set of linearly dependent vectors cannot (all) be mutually orthogonal, but such a set can contain a few mutually orthogonal vectors. In my example above, the set of four vectors was linearly dependent even though three of them ($x$, $y$, and $z$) were mutually orthogonal. This just means the three are orthogonal to each other, but none of these three is orthogonal to the fourth, $u$.

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER, of course they can be, but its only the case when talking about the zero vector, which is orthogonal to itself and any other vector in the vector space. However, I don't think you should think vectors are perpendicular because, how can you define an angle in certain vector spaces?

Comment: @Cheesecake Understood thx. Also please see if [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3697150/eigen-vector-method-vs-correlation-free-coordinates-transformation-method) can be contributed to as well